# How do I set minimum output size when converting video files in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation

This is the function I use to compress video files in Swift:

```
private func compressVideo(inputURL: URL, outputURL: URL, handler:@escaping (_ exportSession: AVAssetExportSession?)-> Void) {
    let urlAsset = AVURLAsset(url: inputURL, options: nil)
    guard let exportSession = AVAssetExportSession(asset: urlAsset, presetName: AVAssetExportPresetLowQuality) else {
        handler(nil)
        return
    }
    exportSession.outputURL = outputURL
    exportSession.outputFileType = AVFileType.mp4
    exportSession.shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = true
    exportSession.exportAsynchronously { () -> Void in
        handler(exportSession)
    }
}
```

But the result is not as I expect;) For example, when I have 17MB size before compression, then as output I get 0.6MB. Is it possible to set somewhere type of compression or something like this to get a result with better quality? I will have satisfied when I get ~2MB file size in output.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `AVAssetExportPresetMediumQuality` for better quality than `AVAssetExportPresetLowQuality`.

Or you can use `AVAssetWriter` for more cutomization